# Multilevel Tree Table filtering ADF 11 2

Tags: tree, filtering, oracle-adf

I have multilevel tree table in adf web fusion application and I want to filter this tree depending on a column in the table my tree looks like:

```
<af:treeTable value="#{bindings.AccountsView1.treeModel}" var="node"
              selectionListener="#{bindings.AccountsView1.treeModel.makeCurrent}"
              rowSelection="single" id="tt1" partialTriggers="::cb1">
  <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
    <af:column id="c1" headerText="Id">
      <af:outputText value="#{node.Id}" id="ot1"/>
    </af:column>
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="pathStamp">
    <af:outputText value="#{node}" id="ot2"/>
  </f:facet>
  <af:column id="c2" headerText="Name">
    <af:outputText value="#{node.Name}" id="ot3"/>
  </af:column>
  <af:column id="c3" headerText="Kind">
    <af:outputText value="#{node.Kind}" id="ot4"/>
  </af:column>
</af:treeTable>
```

My tree has six levels. I want to filter all levels using kind NO.